# Create Virtual Machine on Azure with Java SDK

Tags: azure

I need to create virtual machine from azure java sdk. I integrated maven dependencies into my project. I need a simple tutorial. Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recently azure has rolled out [java api (1.0.0) ][1]as stable release. I will follow 1.0.0 sdk to help you in creating virtual machine.

```
 1. Create a azure authentication file with all credentials

subscription=<enter_subscription>
client=<enter_client>
key=<enter_key>
tenant=<enter_tenant>
managementURI=https\://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https\://management.azure.com/
authURL=https\://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https\://graph.windows.net/

2. Get Azure client to perform an operation in azure

`final File credFile = new File("/Users/risanand/cliqr.azureauth");
 Azure azure = Azure.configure()
 .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BASIC)
 .authenticate(credFile)
 .withDefaultSubscription();`

3. Create virtual machine
    `VirtualMachine windowsVM = azure.virtualMachines().define("vmName")
    .withRegion("regionname")
    .withNewResourceGroup("resourceGroupName")
    .withNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
    .withPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic()
    .withoutPrimaryPublicIPAddress()                   
    .withAdminUsername(userName)
    .withAdminPassword(password)
    .withNewDataDisk(10)
    .withSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.STANDARD_D3_V2)
    .create();`



  [1]: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the VirtualMachineOperationsTest class in the Test Packages, here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/management-compute/src/test/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/management/compute.

Comment: Link in answer is dead.